# doubling error in rounding code

Tags: python, rounding-error

Having an issue with my script where it is doubling in the rounding code and I cant find the error. I can not seem to find where the issue is generating from. Any feedback would be appreciated.

```
def research_rounding(first_time):   
    first_time = float(first_time)   
    if first_time == 0:                     #If time is 0, return 0
        result_time = 0
        return result_time

    else:                                   #If time is not 0, continue rounding func
        first_time = str(first_time)
        find_dec = "."
        length = len(first_time)
        found_dec = (first_time.find(find_dec))
        found_whole = float(first_time[0:found_dec])
        found_tenth = float(first_time[found_dec:length])

        if found_tenth < 0.25 and found_whole >= 1 and found_tenth != 0:
            result_time = 0.25 + found_whole
            return result_time
        elif found_tenth == 0 and found_whole >=1:
            result_time = 0 + found_whole
            return result_time
        elif found_tenth == 0 and found_whole == 0:
            result_time = 0
            return result_time
        elif found_tenth <= 0.5:
            result_time = 0.5 + found_whole
            return result_time
        elif found_tenth > 0.5 and found_tenth < 0.75:
            result_time = 0.75 + found_whole
            return result_time
        elif found_tenth > 0.75 and found_tenth < 1:
            result_time = 1 + found_whole
            return result_time
        else:
            pass
```

Comment: what issue? add an example with expected and current results.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are trying to round to the nearest 1/4, it's a lot easier (and more accurate) to do that numerically, rather than messing around with strings.

```
import math
result_time = math.floor(4*first_time + .5) / 4
```

Floor() truncates to negative infinity, so this approach will work even when first_time is a negative number.